# How to access properties from subclasses in an entity component system

Tags: c++, components, system, entities, subclass

I just started working on an entity component system for a sidescroller game.

I'm pretty new to C++ but I've already read through a lot of tutorials and decided the best way would be to have a entity class which contained a vector of components.There would then be a base component class with the actually components as subclasses.

Entity.h:

```
#ifndef _ENTITY_H
#define _ENTITY_H

#include "header.h"

class Entity

{

public:
    Entity();
    ~Entity();

    // Vector which stores all added components
    vector<Component*> Components;

    // Add component method
    void AddComponent(Component* component);

};

#endif
```

Entity.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
#include "Component.h"
#include "Entity.h"

Entity::Entity(){}

Entity::~Entity(){}

void Entity::AddComponent(Component* component)
{
    Components.push_back(component);
}
```

Component.h:

```
#ifndef _COMPONENT_H
#define _COMPONENT_H

#include "header.h"


class Component

{

public:

    // Forward declaration 
    class Entity;

    Component();
    ~Component();

    void Connect(Entity* entity) {}

    string Name;
};


// Position component
class Position: public Component{ 

public:
    int x, y; 

};

// Display component
class Display: public Component{ 

public:

    sf::Sprite baseSprite; };

#endif
```

Component.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"
#include "Component.h"

Component::Component(){}

Component::~Component(){}
```

Now to add a new component I would do something like this:

```
Entity* new_component;
new_component = new Entity;
new_component->AddComponent(new Position);  
new_component->AddComponent(new Display);
```

The problem is, I don't know how to actually access a component again once I add it.

I would like to be able to access, for example, the x and y values of Position. But when I try to access components in the list like this:

```
Components[i]->...
```

I only come up with the attributes of the base component class.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store certain types of components in a certain index.
For example, all position components are stored in position 0, all velocity components are stored in position 1.

Then you can retrieve the components easily

```
template <class T>
T * Entity::getComponent()
{
    return static_cast<T*>(components[T::getIndex()]);
}
```

Component::getIndex() is a static method that should return the index for that component.

Answer (score 0):

Use `static_cast<T>` or `dynamic_cast<T>` to cast the vector element to the appropriate type before accessing methods of the derived class.

To use `static_cast<T>`, you will have to remember which element is of which type, because the `static_cast<T>` will not tell you.

`dynamic_cast<T>` will return a null-pointer if `T` is not of the appropriate pointer type, but this entails some run time overhead (about which I wouldn't be too concerned).

As a side note, I would seriously consider a redesign so that casting is not necessary.

Comment: Ah, That makes sense. Do you know of any examples of a good design that would not involve casting I could look at? As I am new to C++ and just starting this game I would really like to keep things as simple as possible. Thanks!